# Filter out duplicates from two lists and change object property value if duplicate

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists AuthorList & AuthorList2. At the moment I am using union with simple IEqualityComparer class.
I expect to have a result list without any duplicates from AuthorList & AuthorList2 and if there are any duplicates in those lists, they need to be removed from the lists and the Author class Assigned property needs to be set true for the duplicate item.

Existing information from both AuthorLists:

ProductID & Assigned

- **1**, **false**
- 2, false
- 3, false
- **1**, **false**

Result list:

ProductID & Assigned

- **1**, **true**
- 2, false
- 3, false

The logic needs to filter out duplicates and if both of those lists have the same element, change **false** -> **true**.

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
     class Hello
      {
        static void Main()
        {

            List<Author> AuthorList = new List<Author>
            {
                new Author(1, false),
                new Author(2, false),
                new Author(3, false)
            };


            List<Author> AuthorList2 = new List<Author>
            {
                new Author(1, false)
            };

            var compareById = new AuthorComparer(false);

            var result = AuthorList.Union(AuthorList2, compareById);

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0},{1}", item.ProductId, item.Assigned);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class AuthorComparer : IEqualityComparer<Author>
        {
            private bool m_withValue;

            public AuthorComparer(bool withValue)
            {
                m_withValue = withValue;
            }

            public bool Equals(Author x, Author y)
            {
                return (x.ProductId == y.ProductId);
            }

            public int GetHashCode(Author x)
            {
                return x.ProductId.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        public class Author
        {
            private int productId;
            private bool assigned;

            public Author(int productId, bool assigned)
            {
                this.productId = productId;
                this.assigned = assigned;
            }

            public int ProductId
            {
                get { return productId; }
                set { productId = value; }
            }

            public bool Assigned
            {
                get { return assigned; }
                set { assigned = value; }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: So are you trying to update the elements of `AuthorList` or `AuthorList2`? I suspect a simple `Intersect` call would help here, but it's not clear what result you expect...

Comment: I am trying to update/filter the elements of AuthorList. I expect to have a list without any duplicates and if there are any duplicates in the list, they need to be removed from the list and the Author class Assigned property needs to be set true.

Comment: As an aside, your `Author` class could be a lot simpler if you used automatically-implemented properties: `public int ProductId { get; set; } public bool Assigned { get; set; }` - and ditch the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're looking for is this:

```
AuthorList.ForEach(a => a.Assigned = AuthorList2.Exists(b => b.ProductId == a.ProductId));
```

You don't need the `IEqualityComparer` at all.

Full, working code:

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            List<Author> AuthorList = new List<Author>
            {
                new Author(1, false),
                new Author(2, false),
                new Author(3, false)
            };


            List<Author> AuthorList2 = new List<Author>
            {
                new Author(1, false)
            };

            AuthorList.ForEach(a => a.Assigned = AuthorList2.Exists(b => b.ProductId == a.ProductId));

            foreach (var item in AuthorList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0},{1}", item.ProductId, item.Assigned);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class Author
        {
            public Author(int productId, bool assigned)
            {
                this.ProductId = productId;
                this.Assigned = assigned;
            }

            public int ProductId { get; set; }

            public bool Assigned { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your comparer, you can use:

```
foreach (var author in AuthorList.Intersect(AuthorList2, compareById))
{
    author.Assigned = true;
}
```

You can do it without that easily enough as well if you don't need the comparer for anything else:

```
var author2Ids = new HashSet<int>(AuthorList2.Select(a => a.ProductId));
foreach (var author in AuthorList.Where(a => author2Ids.Contains(a.ProductId)))
{
    author.Assigned = true;
}
```

... but if you need the comparer for anything else, or if it may get more complex, I'd stick to using that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this. Please look at `!` carefully

```
       //Separate out different entries from both the lists
        var diffList = AuthorList.Where(x => !AuthorList2.Any(y => y.ProductId== x.ProductId && y.Assigned== x.Assigned)).ToList();
       //Separate out common entries from both the list
        var commonList = AuthorList.Where(x => AuthorList2.Any(y => y.ProductId== x.ProductId && y.Assigned== x.Assigned)).ToList();
        //Change value of Assigned
        commonList.ForEach(x => x.Assigned = !x.Assigned);
       //Merge both the lists
       diffList.AddRange(commonList);
```

POC: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8LfBng)

Answer (score 0):

This will produce a new List of elements without altering the source:

```
private static List<Author> FilterDuplicates(List<Author> x, List<Author> y)
{
     return x.Select(author => new Author(author.ProductId, y.Exists(a => a.ProductId == author.ProductId))).ToList();
}
```